# Substring_index delimiter in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My CLEAR column contains

```
||premiere|24,3,1999||type|movie||
```

after mysql request

```
UPDATE post SET premiere = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( clear,'premiere|',-1 ),'||',1 )*1
```

PREMIERE becoming 24
Can't understand why not 24,3,1999?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clear, 'premiere|', -1 ), '||', 1 )
from (select '||premiere|24,3,1999||type|movie||' as clear) x
```

You'll see that the return value is what you expect (see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/60236)).

The problem is the `*1`.  It converts the value to a number, by using the leading digits.  Hence, you only get 24.